# Смещение начиная с id

Tags: php, mysql

Есть новостная лента, как получать следующую порцию новостей (10шт) начиная с последней? Дело в том что выдача формируется не по хронологическому порядку, т.е. я должен получать id последней выведенной новости на странице и плясать от неё

И что делать в случае если новость была удалена (мы передали id, который уже не существует)?

Comment: Можно запоминать последний полученный id новости
Использовать range() или limit() в запросе

Comment: Запоминайте не последний ID, а максимальное значение ключа, по которому идет сортировка. Да и собственно какой id можно считать "последним", если сортировка не по нему идет

Comment: Когда задаються такие вопросы надо 1) Показать create запрос. 2) Запрос который вы пытались запустить!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения задачи, к заданной сортировке добавьте сортировку по `id`. В повторный запрос надо передавать значения полей `id` и `поля сортировки` из последней строки первоначального запроса. Запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
 SELECT
      nl.Id,
      nl.'поле сортировки',
      ....
 FROM 'новостная лента' AS nl
 WHERE
   (nl.'поле сортировки' > 'значение поля сортировки из последней строки предыдущего набора')
   OR (
     nl.'поле сортировки' = 'значение поля сортировки из последней строки предыдущего набора'
     AND nl.Id < 'значение id из последней строки предыдущего набора'
      )
 ORDER BY nl.'поле сортировки' ASC, nl.id DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

Пример работы на [rextester](http://rextester.com/DOTQ91408)

Comment: учитывая, что данные выбираются "_не по хронологическому порядку_" скорее всего id идут в перемешку и ориентироваться на них вообще нельзя

Comment: @Mike значит нужно ориентироваться не по `id`, а по столбцу по которому новости отсортированы. А дальше на клиенте отсекать повторно вернувшиеся строки. UPD вижу выше вы тоже самое сказали.

Comment: А не проще отсортировать по тому полю, по которому идет выдача и проверять на больше/меньше не ID а ключ сортировки

Comment: @Mike именно это и имел ввиду.

Comment: @vikolyada к сожалению столбец по которому идет сортировка имеет ооочень много повторов, он не уникален

Comment: @Fangog обновил ответ.

Comment: @vikolyada а что если поле сортировки имеет свойство повторятся? У него не очень большой диапазон, всего от 0 до 10

Comment: @Fangog именно по этому в сортировку последним следует добавлять  уникальное поле таблицы. В данном случае `id`, что позволит дополнительным условием `(nl.'поле сортировки' = 'значение поля сортировки из последней строки предыдущего набора' AND nl.Id < 'значение id из последней строки предыдущего набора')` отсекать все записи попавшие в предыдущую выборку

Comment: @Fangog обновил пример [посмотрите](http://rextester.com/DOTQ91408)